# Steam library sharing question

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

If I have 3 steam accounts, a primary one - the one that has all the games; and 2 empty ones. If I share my library on the primary account to the other two, can both of the other accounts play at the same time (not the same game obviously)?

So for instance: Account 1 Shares 2 games to account 2 and account 3, can account 2 play game 1 while account 3 plays game 2? Or as soon as account 3 comes online account 2 gets disconnected?

Comment: Could you expand on what you are trying to accomplish with this setup? I'm assuming you're just trying to let multiple people play a single copy of a game, but if there's a legitimate reason here we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not without shenanigans that break the terms and conditions.

A single shared library can only be used by one account at once. If that library is in use by account 2, account 3 will be unable to access it at all. Account 1, if it is the owner of the game, can access it but will force account 2 to disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done if after account 2 fires up their game, they disconnect from the internet and play the game in offline mode before account 3 fires up their game but I haven't tried this in a number of years but I believe the method should still work. Ignore this though if you are trying to keep all 3 accounts online at the same time.